# Is a Detrended Correspondance Analysis over time possible?

Tags: time-series, vegan, correspondence-analysis

I have a dataset with **presence-absence species data** measured at several different sites. The data was measured over the span of 10 years. On many sites, measurements were taken several times within a year. The frequency of measurements is not constant nor were all sites measured several times, some were even only measured once.

I know that a classical **Detrended Correspondance Analysis** is not helpful here, since it does not consider the **cofactor time**. Is there any way to include all sampling points or any other correspondance analysis method that is useful here?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to estimate the time effect or partial it out, yes, but not in **vegan**. **Canoco** has detrended canonical correspondence analysis (DCCA), the constrained form of DCA but vegan doesn't and is unlikely to ever have it.

There's nothing stopping you throwing all samples into a DCA you just can't remove the temporal effects.

Alternatively, choose a suitable dissimilarity coefficient and use NMDS via vegan's wrapper `metaMDS()`. This will give you a DCA-like analysis. If you want to account for the temporal effects, then using the same dissimilarity look at `dbrda()` as one option.

Comment: **vegan** will never have DCCA. However, DCA is just an exploratory technique, and nothing stops you from throwing any non-negative data into DCA.